# A java method that has a generic parameter- why can't I pass an object with a generic parameter that is a subclass of the method arguments?

Tags: java, generics

What I mean is, in the code below:

```
class base {

}

class derived extends base {

}

class WTF {

    public void func(List<base> list) {

    }

    public void tryit() {
        func(new List<base>()); // ok
        func(new List<derived>()); // not ok
    }
}
```

But if the function simply took an object of base, it could take a derived object. Why is this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`func` needs to be defined as

```
public void func(List<? extends base> list) { ... }
```

This is because a `List<derived>` is not actually a `List<base>`, because a `List<base>` allows any kind of `base` in it, while a `List<derived>` only allows `derived` and its subclasses. Using `? extends base` ensures that you can't add anything but `null` to the `List`, since you're not sure what subclasses of `base` the list might allow.

As an aside, you should try to follow standard Java naming conventions... classes starting with lowercase letters look strange, like they're primitives.

Answer (score 4):

This is because if passing in a List<derived> was allowed, func() would be able to add base-typed elements to the list, thus invalidating the generic contract of the list (which should only allow for derived-typed contents)

if on the other hand you define func as

```
public void func(List<? extends base> list)
```

you can still retrieve base-typed elements from list, but just won't be able to add any new elements to it, which is exactly the behavior you want.

Answer (score 0):

To explain this behaviour of java, look at this example

```
void addItem(List<Base> list) {
    list.add(new Base());
}

List<Base> l1 = new ArrayList<Base>();
addItem(l1);
Base b = l1.get(0);

List<Derived> l2 = new ArrayList<Derived>();
addItem(l2);
Derived d = l2.get(0); // Would cause runtime exception.
```

That's why this code will not compile in the first place.